# How to draw line in topmost z-oder

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I want to draw line connect two sprites, but i can not do that in this case:

```
//add Map Background
        map = [CCTMXTiledMap tiledMapWithTMXFile:@"orthogonal-test-zorder.tmx"];
        [self addChild:map z:1 tag:kTagTileMap];
//overite draw function
- (void)draw {

    glColor4f(0.8, 1.0, 0.76, 1.0);  
    glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
    ccDrawLine( ccp(0, 0), ccp(150, 150) );
}
```

the line is not shown on screen, if i remove map background , it's shown.

Comment: I don't know Cocos2D so this is just wild guessing, but the `z` parameter of `[self addChild:map z:1 tag:kTagTileMap];` seems to be a `z` offset. Since 1 would be in front of 0 (the likely default), your map would render in front of your line. Try `[self addChild:map z:-1 tag:kTagTileMap];`

Comment: Then I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: Yupz.. draw line would always draw at z:0.. So the only way is to set everything below it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know Cocos2D so this is just wild guessing, but the z parameter of [self addChild:map z:1 tag:kTagTileMap]; seems to be a z offset. Since 1 would be in front of 0 (the likely default), your map would render in front of your line. Try [self addChild:map z:-1 tag:kTagTileMap];

Answer (score 0):

I've encounted same problem 2 days ago.

My solution is to make a seperate MyLineLayer which only draw the line. Then you can set the z-index of the CCLayer to the top.

I think that using an enveloped MyLineLayer would be better than make the z-index of the tile map smaller.